# Possible Reactive function for PDF download in Shiny

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a shiny app being able to download a PDF of selected table content.

For example, if I have two tables, and I select one table to be downloaded via PDF, it will download a PDF that has the title content I want and the specified table in a PDF format. Not sure how I can change the `downloadHandler` portion so that the PDF download works and not give me the following error:

> Warning: Error in FUN: non-numeric argument to binary operator   [No
> stack trace available]

.

The code is as follows:

```
df1<- data.frame(c(1:4),c("Z","Y","X","A"))
df2<- data.frame(c("Apple","Orange"),c(6.99,4.99))
colnames(df1)<-c("Col1","Col2")
colnames(df2)<-c("ColA","ColB")

library(shiny)
library(Cairo)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Test"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Data Table", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("th")))),
  
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
        fluidRow( 
          box(downloadButton("download", "PDF Download"),
              radioButtons(inputId="filter1", label="Table", choiceNames = c("One","Two"), choiceValues = c("df1","df2"),inline= TRUE))),
        fluidRow(box(
              column(8, align="center", offset = 2,tags$b(textOutput("text1"))),
              
              br(),br(),br(),br(),
              textOutput("text2"),
              tableOutput("static1"),
              width=12))
        
      )))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text1 <- renderText({ "This Table" })
  output$text2 <- renderText({"PR"})
  df02 <- reactive({
    get(input$filter1)
  })
  output$static1 <- renderTable({
    df02()
  })
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename =  'report.pdf',
  content = function(file) {
    cairo_pdf(filename = "file123.pdf", 
              df02())
    
  }, contentType = "application/pdf"
)
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**It seems that the PDF download does not work. I want the downloaded PDF to look like this when I select Table One and click on the PDF download button:**

[image]

**I want the downloaded PDF to look like this when I select Table Two to be downloaded:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df1 <- data.frame(c(1:4), c("Z", "Y", "X", "A"))
df2 <- data.frame(c("Apple", "Orange"), c(6.99, 4.99))
colnames(df1) <- c("Col1", "Col2")
colnames(df2) <- c("ColA", "ColB")

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(xtable)
library(withr)
library(shinybusy)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data Table", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("th"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    add_busy_spinner(spin = "cube-grid", onstart = FALSE),
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dashboard",
        fluidRow(
          box(
            downloadButton("download", "PDF Download"),
            radioButtons(
              inputId = "filter1", label = "Table", inline = TRUE,
              choiceNames = c("One", "Two"), choiceValues = c("df1", "df2")
            )
          )
        ),
        fluidRow(box(
          column(8, align = "center", offset = 2, tags$b(textOutput("text1"))),
          br(), br(), br(), br(),
          textOutput("text2"),
          tableOutput("static1"),
          width = 12
        ))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$text1 <- renderText({
    "This Table"
  })
  
  output$text2 <- renderText({
    "PR"
  })
  
  df02 <- reactive({
    get(input$filter1)
  })
  
  output$static1 <- renderTable({
    df02()
  })
  
  output[["download"]] <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "results_from_shiny.pdf",
    content = function(file){
      texfile <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(file), ".tex")
      latex <- print.xtable(
        xtable(df02()), print.results = FALSE, 
        floating = FALSE, scalebox = "0.9"
      )
      writeLines(
        c(
          "\\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}",
          "\\usepackage{graphics}",
          "\\usepackage{caption}",
          "\\begin{document}",
          "{\\large\\bf This table.}",
          "",
          "\\newline",
          "",
          "\\minipage{\\textwidth}",
          "\\centering",
          latex,
          "\\captionof{table}{My caption}",
          "\\endminipage",
          "\\end{document}"
        ),
        texfile
      )
      with_dir(
        dirname(texfile), 
        tools::texi2pdf(texfile, clean = TRUE)
      )
    }, contentType = "application/pdf"
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## EDIT

Or you can use the [capture](https://github.com/dreamRs/capture) package:

```r
tabItem(
  tabName = "dashboard",
  fluidRow(
    box(
      capture::capture_pdf(
        selector = "#table-container",
        filename = "table.pdf",
        icon("camera"), "Take screenshot of table."
      ),
      radioButtons(
        inputId = "filter1", label = "Table", , inline = TRUE,
        choiceNames = c("One", "Two"), choiceValues = c("df1", "df2")
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(box(
    id = "table-container",
    column(8, align = "center", offset = 2, tags$b(textOutput("text1"))),
    br(), br(), br(), br(),
    textOutput("text2"),
    tableOutput("static1"),
    width = 12
  ))
)
```

Comment: I think this answer needs MilkTex in your computer in order to work. Is there a way to work around installing MilkTex and just do a PDF print of the contents inside the second box?

Comment: @SunnyLeague Yeah. Maybe the **shinyscreenshot** package.

Comment: @SunnyLeague Or the **capture** package; see my edit.

Comment: How do I tell the **capture** package to print the PDF in a letter size (8.5" X 11")  format? Let's say if the table df is long and I want **capture** to split this into several letter-size PDF pages, what's the best way to go about doing this? Same goes for small tables like this: how do I tell **capture** to format this to a letter size for printing?