# How to download a text generated in Shiny renderText in PDF?

Tags: r

I'm trying to download a text dynamically according to the data of a `textInput`. I performed some procedures but I couldn't get the PDF file to be downloaded by the user on whatever computer he is.

My code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  textInput(inputId = "text1", label = "Type:", value = "Text download"),
  
  box(
    title = HTML(
    "<style>.box-header {background-color:#00FF00;color:#020202} .box{border:1px solid #333333;}</style>Output"
    ),
    downloadButton("downloadtext1", "Download"),
    textOutput(outputId = "otext1"))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$otext1 <- renderText({
    
    input$text1
    
  })
  
  df02 <- reactive({
    get(input$filter1)
  })
  
  output[["downloadtext1"]] <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "results_from_shiny.pdf",
    content = function(file){
      texfile <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(file), ".pdf")
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like the content generated in `textInput` to be downloaded to any computer by the user.

Comment: There's more to a PDF file than the text it contains.  You need to render the PDF file, not simply ask shiny to download the content and save it a file with a .pdf extension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible Reactive function for PDF download in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73103524/possible-reactive-function-for-pdf-download-in-shiny)